# How to upgrade gnome-shell-extension-openweather in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I've downloaded a extension called gnome-shell-extension-openweather that gives me the weather forecast for my city. Recently when i boot Ubuntu it gives a message that there is a new version for this extension and that I should update.

But it does not say how to update, and there is no button to update it.

Anyone know how to do this?

This is the app website: https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-openweather

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

This will list (with the aid of some browser magic) the extensions that are installed on your system. There will be an update button next to the extensions that can be updated.

[image]